# Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code?

Tags: linux, redhat, openldap, rhel7

I have setup OpenLdap its starting properly after that due to some issue i kill the process.Now when ever i am trying `systemctl start slapd.service` i am getting

> Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status slapd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

this command `journalctl -xe` giving below information

```
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 systemd[1]: Starting OpenLDAP Server Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit slapd.service has begun starting up.
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2898]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2898]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 slapcat[2902]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2909]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2909]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2911]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2911]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2913]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2913]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2915]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2915]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2917]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2917]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 check-config.sh[2894]: Read/write permissions for DB file '/var/lib/ldap/__db.001' are required.
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2919]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2919]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 check-config.sh[2894]: Read/write permissions for DB file '/var/lib/ldap/__db.002' are required.
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2921]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 runuser[2921]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 check-config.sh[2894]: Read/write permissions for DB file '/var/lib/ldap/__db.003' are required.
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit slapd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed. Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state. Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 systemd[1]: slapd.service failed. Nov 28 21:54:36 suredevbana3 polkitd[717]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2887:70553439 (system bus name :1.2956, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1lines 2393-2430/2430 (END)
```

After this i check this `slapd -d 1` which gave me following information
l

```
dap_url_parse_ext(ldap://localhost/)
ldap_init: trying /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: using /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: HOME env is /root
ldap_init: trying /root/ldaprc
ldap_init: trying /root/.ldaprc
ldap_init: LDAPCONF env is NULL
ldap_init: LDAPRC env is NULL
5a1d9112 @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Jun  6 2017 18:04:02) $
        mockbuild@x86-019.build.eng.bos.redhat.com:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
ldap_pvt_gethostbyname_a: host=suredevbana3, r=0
5a1d9112 daemon_init: listen on ldap:///
5a1d9112 daemon_init: 1 listeners to open...
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap:///)
5a1d9112 daemon: bind(7) failed errno=98 (Address already in use)
5a1d9112 daemon: bind(7) failed errno=98 (Address already in use)
5a1d9112 slap_open_listener: failed on ldap:///
5a1d9112 slapd stopped.
5a1d9112 connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
```

Please find below

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v149)
"   /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../
./
cn=schema/
cn=schema.ldif
olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif
olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif
olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif
.swp
```

One more information its started with this command

```
slapd -d -1 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
```

Comment: Can you paste your slapd.conf?

Comment: @DanilaLadner Added information you required.

Comment: It looks like when you're killing the process it may not be killing properly and the process still has control of the socket as evidenced by the `address already in use` and `cannot open listener`. If you're going to kill the service use `systemctl stop slapd` or `systemctl restart slapd` to restart it.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for your reply its starting when i am running it through `slapd -d -1 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d` but issue with `systemctl` only.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Did you try `systemctl restart slapd`?

Comment: @Patrick Thanks its fixed ,you are right ldap process killed wrongly .Now its proper working fine.Another issue we found and same mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
check-config.sh[2894]: Read/write permissions for DB file '/var/lib/ldap/__db.003' are required.
```

slapd runs as `ldap` user by default, if you attempted to start it (or loaded ldif etc..) as root user, it'd create files with incorrect permission. Try `chown -R  ldap.ldap /var/lib/ldap` to fix the permissions and start the service.

Answer (score 1):

I also facing the same problem but I have resolved with below command:

```
setenforce 0
getenforce
```

If you want to persist it:

```
vi /etc/selinux/config
```

Change this parameter `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive`

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable your SELINUX.
2. Install the required certificates specified in the file:

   ```
   olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif
   ```

Comment: Certificates were the issue for me. I generated certificates, but needed to change the ownership to ldap:ldap for the server to start.